# open cv setup issue in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, opencv

I am trying to implement opencv 3.4.1 library in my native android code. I have downloaded opencv for android-pack and i have done the setup but when i'm trying to run the project i'm getting following error in internal file **Imgcodecs.java**

at
**Mat retVal = new Mat(imread_0(filename, flags));**

ERROR:

java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for long org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs.imread_0(java.lang.String, int) (tried Java_org_opencv_imgcodecs_Imgcodecs_imread_10 and Java_org_opencv_imgcodecs_Imgcodecs_imread_10__Ljava_lang_String_2I)
org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs.imread_0(Native Method)

```
    org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs.imread(Imgcodecs.java:115)
```

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

Is there any code segment that I can reproduce the error (I mean the place before sending frame to imread)?

I guess you might forget to call `System.loadLibrary()` for native-lib.   If you want to check that whether OpenCV is added successfully, try to write the below code into the `MainActivity`. [Geeksforgeeks tip](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-add-opencv-library-into-android-application-using-android-studio/):

```
   static{
        if(OpenCVLoader.initDebug()){
            Log.d(“Check”,”OpenCv configured successfully”);
        } else{
            Log.d(“Check”,”OpenCv doesn’t configured successfully”);
        }
    }
```